# I am trying to relate the restaurant_id with the dishes

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a one to many relationship between two tables, restaurant and dishes. I cannot associate the restaurant id with the dishes. I had to put the user_id but doing so if the user has more than one restaurant all the dishes would be mixed. so i should replace the user_id with the restaurant_id

**DishController**

```
class DishController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $dishes = Dish::all();
        $restaurant = Restaurant::all();
        $dishes = Dish::where('restaurant_id', Auth::id())->get();

        return view('admin.dishes.index', compact('dishes', 'restaurant'));
    }

    public function create()
    {   
        return view('admin.dishes.create');
    }

    public function store(Request $request, Restaurant $id)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $data["restaurant_id"]= Auth::id();
        /* $data['slug'] = Str::slug($data['name'], '-'); */
        $new_dish = new Dish();
        $new_dish->fill($data);
        $new_dish->save();

        return redirect()->route('admin.dishes.index', $new_dish);
    }

    public function show($id)
    {
        $dish = Dish::find($id);
        if(!$dish){
            abort(404);
        }

        return view('admin.dishes.show', compact('dish'));
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $dish = Dish::find($id);

        if (!$dish) {
            abort(404);
        }
        return view('admin.dishes.edit', compact('dish'));
    }

    public function update(Request $request, Dish $dish)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $dish->update($data);

        return redirect()->route('admin.dishes.show',$dish);
    }

    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Dish model**

```php
class Dish extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'ingredients', 'price', 'cover', 'visible','restaurant_id'
    ];

    public function restaurant(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Restaurant');
    }

    public function orders(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Why restaurant belongs to restaurant? And there is no `Restaurant` model either ... as a matter of fact, relations can only be created in between models, now read the title you've wrote and see the misconception.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding a hidden field to restaurant_id in your view form

```
<input type="hidden" name="restaurant_id" value={{ $restaurant->id }}>
```

then, in your store method

```
$restaurant = Restaurant::find($request->restaurant_id);
$restaurant->dishes()->create( //Your Atribbutes here//);
```

Comment: where do I put this input? and which store method?

Comment: Put the input in the form that sends your data to your store() method in your controller

Comment: what do you mean by "Your Atribbutes here"? thank you